# Installing TomatoUSB on a Linksys WRT54GL?

Tags: router, firmware, tomato

I don't know whether I'm missing something obvious here, but when I download the TomatoUSB 2.6 VPN build (from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tomatousb/files/Experimental%20%28beta%29/K26-MIPSR1/tomato-K26USB-1.28.9054MIPSR1-beta-vpn3.6.rar/download)), and try and install the included .trx file in the default Linksys router "Firmware upgrade" screen, I get the error "incorrect image file!"

I think it wants a .bin file instead, and indeed the default Tomato firmware comes with a .trx file AND various .bin files, so why doesn't TomatoUSB?  How should I install TomatoUSB onto this router?  Is it safe to just rename the .trx file to .bin, or do I need to get some other file to install it?

Comment: It sounds like the author didn't package the correct files. Contact him for support. Although I highly suspect that Linksys routers do not have Broadcom chips.  Try a different version of the firmware see if the archive contents changes.  A `trx` file IS NOT a `bin` file doing so WILL NOT work.

Answer (score 4):

The answer was that the TomatoUSB image was too large (over 3MB) to be installed directly through the Linksys firmware.  I first installed the [regular Tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato), then used its "Upgrade" screen to upgrade to TomatoUSB (you ARE allowed to upgrade to a .trx file from the regular Tomato firmware).

[This guide](http://tomatousb.org/tut:openvpn) actually tells you to install the "mini" version of DD-WRT first, for some reason, but it works equally well with normal Tomato as it does with that.

Comment: Tested here and it works

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change (rename) trx to bin. As far as I remember, trx is for ASUS routers. But you must check very carefully that you have the correct firmware for your router.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  I suspect what I need to do is first install DD-WRT mini, because the default Linksys firmware can't flash images larger than 3MB (which TomatoUSB is).

Comment: You should go to http://tomatousb.org/ or http://www.linksysinfo.org/index.php and study. And you are probably right in installing DD-WRT mini first.